# Communicate PC and Android Phone (from browser) and call action from phone to PC

Tags: javascript, android, sockets

I have XAMPP installed in my PC, and a website in `localhost/mysite`.

the website has this:

```
<p id="p-1"></p>
```

Then I have a website in `localhost/mysite-2` with this:

```
<button>Click me</button>

<script>
    document.querySelector('#p-1').addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.textContent = 'My text';
    });
</script>
```

I'm oversimplyfying here but that's the main purpose. Is there a way I can achieve this? I think I need sockets right? But how? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Exactly. Specifically, I want to run mysite JS functions from mysite-2 and have mysite send output information from this functions to mysite-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone wants to know how I did it, since it was a simple thing that was only gonna run locally, I didn't use sockets (I never used them and don't know how to and had to finish this fast), I used a txt file as a "database".

I had a function in mysite-2 that, using ajax and php, writes "1" to a txt file when pushing a button.

Then, in website one I have a loop that makes an ajax call to read the file. If it has a "1", it means the button was pushed, so it writes the text and also makes an ajax call to revert the status of the txt to something like "0".

If you need to get more details, PM me or comment here.